# How to speed up small parts of a video file to match an audio file?

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, video-editing

Currently, I have a video which has been originally made in language X.

Now, I have the audio of the same song in language Y and I want to dub the video but there are some slight moments where they run out of sync. These moments can be corrected by changing the speed of the video or audio at certain moments, this should allow them to run simultaneously...

So, is there software that allows me to to **speed up/slow down small parts of the video**?

Changing the audio to match the video with software like Ableton didn't work out well yet...

Comment: +250? nah... +300! Show me what you've got. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Remapping the Video Stream to match the Audio Stream: Introduction

Many years ago, I made a rendered architectural fly-through animation (part of an university group project) where we used [Adobe Premiere](http://www.adobe.com/products/premiere/) and [**Adobe After Effects**](http://www.adobe.com/products/aftereffects/), to edit and manipulate rendered clips that we made in [3DS Max](http://usa.autodesk.com/3ds-max/) to fit to the beats and changes of some [German trance music](http://www.der-dritte-raum.de/).  It worked out very well.  Another group used [**Sony Vegas**](http://www.sonycreativesoftware.com/vegaspro) to do something similar.

These programs are expensive, but they are industry standard tools and skills in using them are highly valued by employers in relevant fields.  There are trial versions which will give you enough time to do what you want to do.

It would be much better to slow down and speed up parts of the video to fit the music, rather than the other way around, as changing the tempo of the music will sound totally wrong, where as it will be unnoticeable visually, as long as it is only a *slight* variation.

### Remapping the Video Stream to match the Audio Stream: Procedure

There are loads of tutorials on the internet.  Here are a couple which I found from a quick search:

[Time remapping in Adobe After Effects](http://library.creativecow.net/articles/preston_bryan/time_remapping.php) (this is for an old version of After Effects, but I doubt that the technique would have changed much since, although there may be new tools now which makes the process easier)

[Time syncing video to music in Sony Vegas](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=az7PIkc8Xkw) (YouTube Video)

Answer (score 1):

### Remapping the Audio Stream to match the Video Stream.

For modifying the audio stream there is a program called Audacity that works well. You should be able to download it, and select the portion of song you want speed up or slow down to implement the changes.

Remember to download the [LAME MP3 encoder](http://lame.sourceforge.net/) as well if you want to be able to export the file as an `.mp3`.

Comment: Sorry, I've even tried Ableton Live. I think I better break the thing which I don't like instead of breaking down the thing that I like. So, I better modify the video which I currently don't like (as it doesn't match and is in another language) than the audio that I like...

Answer (score 1):

A freeware solution is apparently Windows Movie Maker.

Download and install [Custom Speed Effects for Movie Maker(XP & Vista)](http://movies.blainesville.com/2007/02/custom-speed-effects-for-movie-maker-xp.html).
You will also find many other effects for WMM in that site which you can download free.
After installing, you'll have new custom speed effects for :

- Slow Down in increments of 25%, 50%, 66%, x3, x4, x6, x8
- Speed Up in increments of 25%, 50%, 66%, x3, x4, x6, x8

A commercial solution is [Roxio Creator](http://www.roxio.com/enu/products/creator/suite/overview.html) ($79.99).
One [source](http://forums.support.roxio.com/topic/51495-is-there-a-speed-upslow-down-video-filter/) says :

> Right click on the segment you want to
>   speed-up/slow down and select Trim
>   from the drop down list. There is a
>   adjust speed option on the Trim window.

Comment: WMM seems too limited as a jump of 25% in speed is a lot, but +1 for mentioning Roxio.

Comment: I have extracted the files of Custom Speed Effects and found that all it does is install one XML file in `C:\Program Files\Movie Maker\Shared\AddOnTFX`. The contents seem extremely simple, so you could just roll your own speed effects at 5%, 10% or whatever.